# I cant enter a decimal value when I code like this, is there any other way to get result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm making an Input box with will show 0 if no number is entered and shows the actual number if something other than 0 is entered, I've done this but can't use decimal number with it.

Right now I cannot insert "." after a number 
Because If there is a number say 5 and I type 5. then value = 5. * 1 = 5
So it never prints the decimal

```
<input type="number" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} disabled={!isEditMode} />


 handleChange(e) { 
        let value = e.target.value;
        if(value == ''){
              value = 0;
         }else{
              value = e.target.value * 1
         }                
         this.props.updateProjectProperties(e.target.name, value);
//The above this.props basically send the data to another component and get the same back so its irrelevant 
 }
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 1?

Comment: ^ this. Also use `Number()` to parse the string in `e.target.value`

Comment: @0xc14m1z if I enter 0 at first then its gonna be a value and then if I type say 5 then it will show 05 
To not do that I used *1
05*1 = 5